# Files and folder copy using QT pro file

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake

I have a folder called `resources` and inside I have 2 files and 1 folder

> /Hello.txt
>
> /Hello1.txt
>
> /Newfolder

Using Qt `*.pro` file, I need to copy the contents in `resources` into some destination folder. `*.pro` file :

```
BINARY_PATH = $$PWD/../Bin/
RESOURCE_PATH = $$PWD/../resources/

win32 {
QMAKE_POST_LINK +=$$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${RESOURCE_PATH} $${BINARY_PATH}$$escape_expand(\n\t))
}
```

But nothing is getting copied to destination directory.

Comment: What is the difference with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751924/copy-files-and-folders-from-directory-in-qt-pro-file)?

Comment: Question is same but I am not getting any support from that question thats y posted new

Comment: That sounds like spamming..., see [ask]