# Qmake Command to copy directory and files

Tags: windows, qt4, xcopy

I want to copy the contents in directory "temp" to "dd"

```
BINARY_DESTINATION_PATH = $$PWD$$SEPARATOR/dd/
RESOURCE_SOURCE_PATH = $$PWD$$SEPARATOR/temp

EXPORTED_DESTINATION_PATH = $${BINARY_DESTINATION_PATH}
EXPORTED_DESTINATION_PATH ~= s,/,\\,g

EXPORTED_SOURCE_PATH = $${RESOURCE_SOURCE_PATH}
EXPORTED_SOURCE_PATH ~= s,/,\\,g

QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = sample
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32 {
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c xcopy /S /I /Y $${EXPORTED_HEADERS}\\copy_to_output $${EXPORTED_HEADERS_WIN})
}
```

but this is not adding the files into dd and showing error on build.
Error i son line "QMAKE_POST_LINK"

Comment: Does this post helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output

Comment: It is giving details about file copy, I can able to copy files but directory copy is not working

Answer (score 0):

> [quote(string)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#quote-string)
>
> Converts a whole string into a single entity and returns the result. This is just a fancy way of enclosing the string into double quotes.

What you're probably looking for is [`system(command)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#system-replace).